# How to use sed or awk selectively regarding the line length (file-by-file)

Tags: numpy, awk, sed

I've got around 100 formatted files in the following format

```
[[ 1.102      -0.26499999  0.        ]
 [ 2.25999999 -0.88700002  0.        ]
 [-0.152       2.78900003  0.        ]
 [-2.23300004 -1.19700003  0.        ]
 [-2.30699992  1.43700004  0.        ]]
```

where some files are in the form

```
[[ -1.22399998e+00  -4.05999988e-01  -0.00000000e+00]
 [ -2.00000009e-03   1.70599997e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.29299998e+00  -3.49999994e-01  -0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.20299995e+00   1.10699999e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.12299991e+00   1.67100000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
```

which is, however, unpredictable for me when I get this output.

I'd like to have these numbers being rounded to three decimals in the upper form. I've tried things like `sed 's/^\(.\{8\}\).\{4\}/\1/' file`, but this isn't specific regarding the length of a line (and it also doesn't round the numbers, obviously).
I'm sure that NumPy could do this, but I think `sed` or `awk` would do the job more efficient.

**Additional information:** If this is of interest, the output represents coordinates and comes from pymol, which uses `NumPy` for this.

### Edit:

It doesn't matter wether the number of characters between two decimal points in a line differs from the example; having all files formatted in the same way is of interest, which means in detail that

- the decimal points are placed in the same three columns (character positions).
- every file has the same notation of numbers (e. g. decimal, scientific).
- the brackets are either in every output/file at the very same position(s) or in none of any output/file.
- the number of decimals differs neither in a file nor between them.

In short: the only difference between the files is the numeric characters representing the numbers and not how, how exact or where they're written.

Desired output of the above examples:

```
[[ 1.102      -0.264       0.000    ]
 [ 2.256      -0.887       0.000    ]
 [-0.152       2.789       0.000    ]
 [-2.233      -1.197       0.000    ]
 [-2.307       1.437       0.000    ]]

[[-1.224      -4.056      -0.000    ]
 [-2.000       1.706       0.000    ]
 [ 1.293      -3.500      -0.000    ]
 [ 1.203       1.107       0.000    ]
 [ 2.123       1.671       0.000    ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massage the output spacing in  the `printf` to suit whatever criteria works for you if this doesn't as-is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/[][]+/," & ")
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) {
        $i = sprintf("%.3f",$i)
    }
    printf "%2s%6s%12s%12s    %-2s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
[[ 1.102      -0.265       0.000    ]
 [ 2.260      -0.887       0.000    ]
 [-0.152       2.789       0.000    ]
 [-2.233      -1.197       0.000    ]
 [-2.307       1.437       0.000    ]]

[[-1.224      -0.406      -0.000    ]
 [-0.002       1.706       0.000    ]
 [ 1.293      -0.350      -0.000    ]
 [ 1.203       1.107       0.000    ]
 [ 2.123       1.671       0.000    ]]
```

The above was run against this input file:

```
$ cat file
[[ 1.102      -0.26499999  0.        ]
 [ 2.25999999 -0.88700002  0.        ]
 [-0.152       2.78900003  0.        ]
 [-2.23300004 -1.19700003  0.        ]
 [-2.30699992  1.43700004  0.        ]]

[[ -1.22399998e+00  -4.05999988e-01  -0.00000000e+00]
 [ -2.00000009e-03   1.70599997e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.29299998e+00  -3.49999994e-01  -0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.20299995e+00   1.10699999e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.12299991e+00   1.67100000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lpe 's/([-0-9.e+]+) */sprintf "%.3f ", $1/ge' -- file
```

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-p` processes the input line by line and prints each line after processing
- `s///` is substitution, similar to the same command in sed
- `/e` interprets the replacement as code and runs it, which in this case means every number is formatted using [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf).

Comment: +1 for this nearly working solution in one line (I expected two because of the two places per line to replace). Unfortunately, it doesn't give me an extra space(bar) when the number doesn't contain a minus. It'd be great if you could modify this elegant solution working also with partly signed numbers.

Comment: Could you update the question with the expected output for the given input files?